# Power BI paginated report collapsable metrix showing plus sign when the metrix is already expanded initially

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have created a metrix in Power BI paginated report using Power BI report builder. The metrix is made collapsable/expandable by using the metrxi wizard in the report builder. This option basically uses the toggle items to show or hide the subgroup in the parent group

When the report is intially run, the tables is in collapsed status and the collapsed items shows plus sign meaning that the items are expandables. When you expand an line item, it expands and shows a minus sign meaning that it can be collapsed.

The problem begins when we want to fully expand the metrix when the report is intially run. The expanded items shows a plus sign and the collapsed items shows a minus sign

Be default, the subgroups are hidden/collapsed and when you click on the plus icon, the metrix is expanded as shown below

[image: Collapsed table with plus signs]

As you can see, the group is collapsed and shown with a plus sign. When I would expand a group, the plus would change into a minus and the metrix would expand as shown below and highted yellow

[image]

The above is the normal behaviour that you can expect.

Now the customers wanted the metrix to be fully expanded when the report is run initially. I made this possible by going to the group property and checking the show option when the report is initially run. This worked fine and the report is fully expanded when run initially. However, the problem is that the icon still remains plus initially when the metrix is collapsed (after changing the property to show intially). When I would click on the icon to collapse the group, the group collapses but the icon is minus for the collapsed items and plus for the expanded items. Please sow below

[image]

Please look at 04 and 05 items group which are highlighted in yellow. 04 is fully collapsed but showing a minus sign while 05 is expanded but showing a plus sign. This is only happening if I am showing the group items initially when the report is run.

This means that the metrix is somehow designed to show the plus sign intially and toggle to minus sign when clicked (no matter whether the group was collapsed or expanded based on properties). This means that if you would hide the group intially, The plus sign would align with collapsed items and minus would be with expanded items. However, if you show the group initially, then plus sign would align with expanded items initally and minus would align with collapsed items.

When this is exported to excel then excel works normally and shows plus with collapsed items and minus with expanded items no matter what the intial status of the report is. The bug is somehow only with the paginated report.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Each text box within your matrix has an InitialToggleState in the Properties pane under Visibility.  Select the left-most text-box and set this property to True, since you have the group expanded initially.  Whether using True/False or an expression, the InitialToggleState property must be maintained separately along with the group's visibility condition.